# Spring Rest exception handler return XML format

Tags: java, xml, spring, exception

I'm handling an exception in my project

**This is my GET endpoint:**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<V6SubnetRec> get(@RequestBody V6SubnetRequest requestBody) throws QIPException {
    Site site = getSite(requestBody.getOrganization());
    V6SubnetRec wsSubnet = (V6SubnetRec) requestBody.getV6Subnet();
    V6SubnetRec v6SubnetRec = null;
    try {
        v6SubnetRec = getQipService1().getV6Subnets(wsSubnet, site);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(Keys.QIP_CALLOUT_ERROR, e);
        throw new RestException(e);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<V6SubnetRec>(v6SubnetRec, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@ExceptionHandler(RestException.class)
public ResponseEntity rulesForRestException(RestException restEx){
    return new ResponseEntity(restEx.getResponse().getContent(), restEx.getResponse().getStatus());
}
```

**RestException.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "RestException")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class RestException extends RuntimeException{

   @XmlElement
   RestResponse response;

   public RestException(Exception e){
     //...
   }
}
```

When I request with URL http://localhost/api/v1/v6subnet.json (return with JSON format), it will return HTTP status code 404 and include the content. It's OK.
[image]

But when I request with URL http://localhost/api/v1/v6subnet.xml (return with XML format) with the same request, it return HTTP status code 500 like a normal exception which is not handled as JSON format

[image]

I want to have results like when I request to JSON format.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed my issue. It's only change from

```
restEx.getResponse().getContent()
```

into

```
restEx.getResponse().getContent().toString()
```